# NodeJS - Middleware: не понимаю порядок выполнения

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь понять порядок выполнения, но все как-то запутано:

```
var ua = 'foo';

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    ua = 'barr';
    next();
});

app.use(
    session({
        key: ua,
        secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
        store: sessionStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    })
);
```

как я понял, `middleware`'ы выполняются по порядку ( сверху-вниз ), и по идее, переменной `ua` должно успеть приcвоиться значение `bar`, но этого не происходит. объяснить, почему?

P.S. создал промежуточный обработчик, потому что нужно присвоить значение из `req` для сессий

---

разве есть разница между вызовами:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    session({
        key: key,
        secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
        store: sessionStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    })

   next();
});

# и

app.use(
    session({
        key: key,
        secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
        store: sessionStore,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    })
);
```

Comment: все происходит, просто в момент вызова `{
        key: ua,` еще не выполнилась строка `ua = 'barr';`

Comment: _разве есть разница между вызовами_ - огромнейшая! и заключается в том. **когда** выполняется функция `session` и вычисляется параметр для нее

Comment: @Grundy  `еще не выполнилась строка` - разве все не должно выполняться по порядку? сначала присваивается значение переменной, потом выполняется следующий `middleware` - где вызывается `session`

Comment: суть в том, что в случае `app.use(
    session({` аргументы  для session вычисляются не внутри middleware.

Comment: вот хороший скринкаст про middleware https://youtu.be/2Xp9yj3UIAg